# Where can I get the first Blender 2.8 build?

Tags: versions

I have been testing just about every Blender 2.8 build out there to test the new EEVEE engine. I would like to compare the first build with EEVEE and the latest build in a video but I can't find the first Linux version of EEVEE. Could anyone help me get the very first Blender 2.8 version that had EEVEE in it? It would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I believe that that is impossible with the downloads from blender.org, as updates come in full iterations, the best thing to do would be to compare the dev build now to the final version when released. The dev builds are constantly updated and if existing builds need to be updated they add lettering e.g. (2.78a, 2.78b, 2.78c) which is what happened when fixes needed to be released for 2.78. So you would be hard-pressed to find a reliable source of the very very first "Blender 2.8".

Comment: http://download.blender.org/release/

Comment: **https://download.blender.org/release/** the site with all versions of blender i think

Answer (score 1):

> the first build with EEVEE

is a rather arbitrary point in time, the blender 2.80 evee development started as a branch from the current development of blender, it was identical to the normal blender releases. There have been no tagged releases containing evee, the daily test builds have been the only available versions.

As blender is open source, [you can build](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender) any variation of it that you want. The blender 2.80 development is being done in it's own branch so you just add `git branch blender2.8` after you have a copy of the repo. You can list the [history of the branch](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/history/blender2.8/) and checkout any commit from that list that you want and compile it as it was at that point in time.

So you can build any version that you want, but to get daily experimental pre-built binaries you have to get them the day they are available.

Answer (score -1):

Go to official website of [Blender](https://www.blender.org/)

Click on Download

[image]

Scroll down and Click Latest Experimental Builds

[image]

Scroll down to find **These builds are from the Blender 2.8 project. Do not use in the production nor save important file with it**

Below you can find which OS or Mac or linux your using and download it.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. The question is how to get the *first* build of 2.8 with Eevee.